# aggrid dynamically change row height and header height

Tags: ng-grid, angular-grid

I have a specific question about angulargrid. I am trying to implement a feature which would dynamically change the grid size based on the row count. This feature is not currently supported by angulargrid. Therefore, I looked in to ng-grid which has similar functionalities to ag-grid. My question is it possible to implement that gridHeight feature in ng-grid in ag-grid the same way. Something like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
   { name:'id', width:50 },
   { name:'name', width:100, pinnedLeft:true },
   { name:'age', width:100, pinnedRight:true  },
   { name:'address.street', width:150  },
   { name:'address.city', width:150 },
   { name:'address.state', width:50 },
   { name:'address.zip', width:50 },
   { name:'company', width:100 },
   { name:'email', width:100 },
   { name:'phone', width:200 },
   { name:'about', width:300 },
   { name:'friends[0].name', displayName:'1st friend', width:150 },
   { name:'friends[1].name', displayName:'2nd friend', width:150 },
   { name:'friends[2].name', displayName:'3rd friend', width:150 },
];

   $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
   .success(function(data) {
       $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
   });

$scope.randomSize = function () {
    var newHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (300 - 100 + 1) + 300);
    var newWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 - 200 + 1) + 200);

angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('grid')[0]).css('height',   newHeight + 'px');
angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('grid')[0]).css('width', newWidth + 'px');
};
}]);
```